# Convert first order logic into Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to formulate the following FOL sentence as Prolog rule and have absolutely no clue how to do that. (I am new to Prolog):

"If two terminals are connected, then they have the same signal."
In first order logic this would be:

```
FORALL(T1, T2) : Terminal(T1) AND Terminal(T2) AND Connected(T1, T2) => Signal(T1) = Signal(T2)
```

I do know, how "and" is written in Prolog and also that you do not need a FORALL. My problem ist, that the left side can only be one predicate.
This is part of a larger problem, the complete rule set would be:

1. If two terminals are connected, then they have the same signal
2. Connected is commutative
3. The signal at every terminal is either 1 or 0
4. There are four types of gates (and, or, xor, neg)
5. An and gate's output is 0 if and only if any of its inputs is 0
6. An or gate's output is 1 if and only if any of its inputs is 1
7. An xor gate's output is 1 if and only if its inputs are different
8. A neg gate's output is different from its input
9. The gates (except for neg) have two inputs and one output
10. A circuit has terminals up to its input and output arity, and Nothing beyond its arity
11. Gates, terminals, signals, gate types, and Nothing are all distinct
12. Gates are circuits

I am currently trying to formulate the rules, I will post them as soon as I am finished. This is what I have so far (first line with % is natural language, second line with % is an intuitive FOL representation, lines thereafter are my attempt of a Prolog rule):

```
%If two terminals are connected, then they have the same signal:
%all(T1, T2) : terminal(T1), terminal(T2), connected(T1, T2) => signal(T1) = signal(T2).
same_value(T1, T2) :- terminal(T1), terminal(T2), connected(T1, T2).

%Connected is commutative:
%all(T1, T2) :- connected(T1, T2) <=> connected(T2, T1).
connected(T1, T2) :- connected(T2, T1).

%The signal at every terminal is either 1 or 0:
%all(T) :- terminal(T) => signal(T) == 1; signal(T) == 0.
terminal(T) :- signal(T) = 1; signal(T) = 0.

%There are four types of gates:
%all(G) :- (gate(G), K = type(G)) => (K == and; K == or; K == xor; K == neg).

%An and gate's output is 0 if and only if any of its inputs is 0:
%all(G) :- gate(G), type(G) == and => signal(out(1, G)) = 0 <=> some(N), signal(in(N, G)) == 0.
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == or, signal(in(1, G)) == 0; signal(in(2, G)) == 0) => 0.
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == or, signal(in(1, G)) == 1, signal(in(2, G)) == 1) => 1.
%this produces an error: Operator expected

%An or gate's output is 1 if and only if any of its inputs is 1:
%all(G) :- gate(G), type(G) == or => signal(out(1, G)) = 1 <=> some(N), signal(in(N, G)) == 1.
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == or, signal(in(1, G)) == 0, signal(in(2, G)) == 0) => 0.
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == or, signal(in(1, G)) == 1; signal(in(2, G)) == 1) => 1.
%this produces an error: Operator expected

%An xor gate's output is 1 if and only if its inputs are different:
%all(G) :- gate(G), type(G) == xor => signal(out(1, G)) = 1 <=> signal(in(1, G)) \= signal(in(2, G)).
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == xor, signal(in(1, G)) == signal(in(2, G))) => 0.
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == xor, signal(in(1, G)) \= signal(in(2, G))) => 1.
%this produces an error: Operator expected

%A neg gate's output is different from its input:
%all(G) :- gate(G), type(G) == neg => signal(out(1, G)) = not(signal(in(1, G))).
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == neg, signal(in(1, G)) == 1) => 0.
signal(out(1, G)) :- (gate(G), type(G) == neg, signal(in(1, G)) == 0) => 1.
%this produces an error: Operator expected

%The gates (except for neg) have two inputs and one output:
%all(G) :- gate(G), type(G) == neg => arity(G, 1, 1).
%all(G) :- gate(G), K = type(G), (K == and; K == or; K == xor) => arity(G, 2, 1).
arity(G, 1, 1) :- gate(G), type(G) == neg.
arity(G, 2, 1) :- gate(G), (type(G) == and; type(G) == or; type(G) == xor).

%A circuit has terminals up to its input and output arity, and nothing beyond its arity:
%all(C, I, J) :- circuit(C), arity(C, I, J) =>
%   all(N), (N =< I => terminal(in(C, N))), (N > I => in(C, N) = nothing),
%   all(N), (N =< J => terminal(out(C, N))), (N > J => out(C, N) = nothing).

%Gates, terminals, signals, gate types, and Nothing are all distinct:
%all(G, T) :- gate(G), terminal(T) => G \= T \= 1 \= 0 \= or \= and \= xor \= neg \= nothing.

%Gates are circuits:
%all(G) :- gate(G) => circuit(G).
circuit(G) :- gate(G).
```

Comment: Have you familiarized yourself with Prolog at all via tutorial or book? FYI, the first expression, *If two terminals are connected, then they have the same signal* is quite directly and trivially translatable into a Prolog predicate. You don't need the FORALL. The `AND` is very basic: it's a comma.

Comment: @lurker: that's not completely true, In Prolog, one defines an order. *Answer Set Programming* is in many cases better to specify (real) logic.

Comment: @CommuSoft, I agree, not always true. I was saying for the OP's expressed case, not having any additional info, it's a simple predicate.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is not straightforward.  A first possibility:

```
    sameSignal(T1,T2) :- terminal(T1),terminal(T2),
                         connected(T1,T2).
```

A more complicated, assuming that `term(T,S)` means 'the terminal T has signal S'

```
    checkSignals(term(T1,S1), term(T2,S2)) :- terminal(T1), terminal(T2), 
                                              connected(T1,T2), S1=S2.
```

or simply using the same variable:

```
    checkSignals(term(T1,S), term(T2,S)) :- terminal(T1), terminal(T2),
                                            connected(T1,T2).
```

If this is part of a more general problem please show the whole problem to look for a better solution.